# Windows 10 pc will shut off screen when not in use, but will randomly come back on

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I have a sleep timer for my pc, and when it goes off the screen obviously goes black. A minute or two later it comes back on. I've tried `powercfg -lastwake` on cmd and it just says `wake history count - 0`, so I can't figure out what's waking my pc. Is there any way to figure out what it is and prevent it?

Comment: is it doing updates?  Windows Update Restarts can wake up a computer

Comment: To elaborate on @John's comment, there are many tasks that will wake a PC to run.  If you're using an external mouse and disconnect it from the PC, does it still wake?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please type into your Cortana Search bar Power and Sleep. The Cortana search bar is on the bottom of your desktop on the left.
2. The Start Menu will pop up and then you will left-click Power and Sleep.
3. A new window will open and in that window, there will be a blue link that says "Additional Power Settings". Left-click that link.
4. Another smaller window will open. There will be another blue link that says "Change Plan Settings". Please left-click that. Then left-click advanced power settings.
5. Another window will open even smaller than the last.
6. Scroll down to Sleep. There will be a plus sign + please left-click the plus sign.
7. Another + sign will be next to the phrase "Allow wake timers" click that plus sign and then you will click the phrase "enabled" or "Important wake timers" and then select disable. Then at the bottom click apply and hit ok.